# How to pass File type value to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have input type file control in view and I would like to send selected attached file to controller.

But the value is always null for file parameter in Controller action as shown below.

Please let me how to send file details to controller using ajax.

View:

```
<div>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDdocument, IdList, new { id = "ddlFileType" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { id = "txtDescription" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file", id="txtFile" })
  @Html.ActionLink("Add", "", "ESignature", new { }, new { id = "lnkAddAttachment" })
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("#lnkAddAttachment").click(function (e) {
    var fileType = document.getElementById("ddlFileType").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("txtDescription").value;
    var selectedFile = document.getElementById('txtFile').files[0];

    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/AddAttachment?type=" + fileType + "&desc=" + desc + "&file=" + selectedFile;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: $('#frmRegistration').serialize(),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function () {                  
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration"
            $('#gridAttachments').load(url+' #gridAttachments')
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddAttachment(BRUser brUser, string type, string desc, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     // Here I am getting all values except for file parameter
}
```

Model:

```
public class BRUser
{
    public string IDdocument { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: What did you specify as your form method? You need to specify a POST method e.g. `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttachment", "CONTROLLER", null, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype =   "multipart/form-data"}))`

Comment: I am not using POST. I need to get the values in GET method itself.

Comment: You need to use a POST request.

Comment: If I use post, entire page gets refreshed. Here I am trying to refresh  only grid after selecting the file.